# Segue/Transition between two views in a storyboard w/o a NavigationController

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

Is it possible to not use a NavigationController and change views with an animation/segue with a storbyboard. I cant seem to figure out how to accomplish this. I thought it would have been pretty simple but no luck. I just have two views and want to transition without adding a navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just create the segue and select "modal" in the menu that pops up instead of "push".

When you want to return you do it programmatically with:

```
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Is there any simple way to still use the "modal" segue but have the view controller come in from the right side of the screen instead of sliding in from the bottom?

Comment: Ah! In the storyboard if you click on the arrow that is created between the two viewControllers then go to the property inspector you can adjust the transition style there :)

Answer (score 2):

T.J. is right about selecting a `modal` segue, but [`-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) is deprecated in iOS 5+.

You should use [`-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) instead.

With the advent of iOS 6, you may also be able to use 'unwind actions' for dismissing presented controllers with unwind segues.